# Emacs Bulk install packages

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm using [This](http://truongtx.me/2013/01/07/emacs-package-manager/) advice, trying to get Emacs to manage my packages for me. I cannot get Emacs to eval this bit of code, which should install all of my packages, but currently it does absolutely nothing. Is there some error in my elisp that I'm not seeing?

```
;;; Emacs is not a package manager, and here we load its package manager!
(require 'package)
(dolist (source '(("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/")
                  ("elpa" . "http://tromey.com/elpa/")
                  ;; TODO: Maybe, use this after emacs24 is released
                  ;; (development versions of packages)
                  ("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/")
                  ))
  (add-to-list 'package-archives source t))
(package-initialize)

;;; Required packages
;;; everytime emacs starts, it will automatically check if those packages are
;;; missing, it will install them automatically
(when (not package-archive-contents)
  (package-refresh-contents))
(defvar tmtxt/packages
  '(evil git-gutter monokai-theme magit markdown-mode evil-leader jedi evil-surround arduino-mode evil-nerd-commenter zeal-at-point))

(dolist (p tmtxt/packages)
  (lambda () 
      (when (not (package-installed-p p))
        (package-install p))
      (require p)))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The body of your `dolist` is a mere "lambda-expression", i.e. it immediately evaluates to a function which is immediately thrown away.  Since you want the function's body to be executed, just remove the `(lambda () ...)` wrapper:

```
(dolist (p tmtxt/packages)
  (when (not (package-installed-p p))
    (package-install p))
  (require p))
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly. How can you tell when a function (like `dolist`) takes single or multiple arguments? Because I was just trying to find a way to pass multiple functions as a single argument to `dolist`.

Comment: To group several operations into one, you need to use `progn`.  `lambda` is for something else (i.e. to make a function which is a *value* (i.e. *evaluating* such a lambda expression will not run any of the commands inside it) you can pass around or store in variables so that you can **later** *call* it at which point the commands in its body will be executed).

Comment: Is there a way to immediately call a lambda function?

Comment: Lambdas can be called like so: `((lambda ...) arg1 arg2 ...)`.  I'm not a lisp guru, but I think a `let` is equivalent to that and much more idiomatic.

Comment: `C-h f dolist` tells you which arguments it takes. Whenever you see `BODY` as an argument (*especially* with an ellipsis, but the name is really enough) you can assume that it may be multiple expressions.

Comment: Calling a function immediately is not very useful.  It's like wrapping your hamburger in a paper only to immediately unwrap it and eat it: extra work and not benefit.